# ApplicationController Functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, applicationcontroller

I have an app with guest user functionality in it.  I'm trying to understand how my applicationcontroller guest_user methods are being called.  I thought I would need a before_filter in the applicationcontroller in order for them to be called but when I comment out before_filter, the methods are still being called.  Does applicationcontroller automatically call these?  This seems like a simple question but I couldn't really find it spelled out anywhere.  I used this guide to create my guest_user functionality https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user  I'm using rails 3.1.1, formtastic 2.0.2, and devise 1.5.1.  Thanks!

Comment: if you call somewhere current_or_guest_user (or any other method calling guest_user inside) - then it is called from that method. if not - would be very nice to see the controller code, not enough info for now

Comment: @alony I figured out I was calling current_or_guest_user through another method sorry, thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I was calling the current_or_guest_user method through another method in one of my controllers.  It was my first time working with the ApplicationController so I was quick to assume that was responsible, I'll be more careful next time before I make a question.  Thanks.